# Como colocar clique em itens de uma lista no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

Por enquanto meu código esta assim ? como implemento o click dos itens da lista
o click seria para abrir uma nova tela

```
    ListView lista_teste = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_teste);
    String[] dados = new String[]{"xxxxx","xxxx"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dados){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            // Get the Item from ListView
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            // Initialize a TextView for ListView each Item
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            // Set the text color of TextView (ListView Item)
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            // Generate ListView Item using TextView
            return view;
        }
    };
    lista_teste.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

João, para isso você tem que adicionar o evento setOnItemClickListener, veja um exemplo do evento do clique e abrindo uma nova tela:

```
lista_teste.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, SegundaTela.class);                
                // chama a nova tela
                startActivity(mIntent);
                // destrói a tela atual
                finish();

            }
        });
```

Comment: nesse exemplo qualquer item que eu clicar vai fazer isso nao é?

Comment: Sim. Esqueci de colocar um comando. Depois de executar o startActivity é necessário destruir a tela atual, com o comando Finish();

Comment: da pra separa por posição tbm tipo se item posição 1 selecionado abre tela 1 se posição 2 selecionada abir tela 2? procurei e nao achei, no caso essa seria minha necessidade

Comment: sim, dentro do método onItemClick, ele traz o parâmetro position, que é o elemento que foi clicado. Você pode fazer, se position = 1 abre a tela 1, se position = 2 abre a tela 2 e assim por diante.

Comment: vlw em muito obrigado